# Resizing div's height by iframe's height

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, height

I'm struggling to solve this issue. I got this page - http://www.wheelsmarket.ro/informatii - where if you click on the third big button called "Baza de date PCD", a div will appear. Inside that div, is an iframe. The source of the iframe is on the same host as the website.

My problem is making the parent div (the one that appears when you click the button) to resize (like an height:auto) in function of iframe's height.

This is the iframe src - http://wheelsmarket.ro/baza-date

Here is the code @ iframe + the parent div

```
<div style="width:900px; height:100%" id="bazaDatePcd">
<iframe src="http://wheelsmarket.ro/baza-date" width="120%" height="100%"  marginheight="0" frameborder="0""></iframe>                  
<div id="spatiuCalc"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Grab the iFrames height and then apply it to the div;

```
var bazaDatePcd = document.getElementById('bazaDatePcd');
bazaDatePcd.style.height = bazaDatePcd.getElementsByTagName('iframe').offsetHeight;
```

Bind this to an onclick event for the button.

Comment: By binding you mean creating a function or so with that code inside? Excuse my noobiness, but i'm new to all this.